# how to continue completed tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
public int CalcGroup(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
        CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
        if (cts.IsCancellationRequested == true && TaskWorkStatus.IsContinue == false) return 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _paralellTaskCount; i++)
        {
            int counter = CheckCounter(message);
            if (counter >= 0)
            {
                var myTask = new Task<long>(() => CalcSingle(_personnelIds[counter].Item1), ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                if(myTask.IsCompleted)
                    myTask.ContinueWith(t => CalcSingle(_personnelIds[counter].Item1), ct);
                else
                    myTask.Start();

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

In above code block I want to run tasks that are `Canceled` and `Completed`, but it doesn't work.
What is my mistake?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use async await?

Answer (score 1):

0) Creating a new Task via the constructor is a bad practice since running it will later incur extra overhead(you can google the why's and how's later). Use Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew, depending on your .NET version.. (I've recently learned that Task.Run is a better practice for .NET 4.5 and later).

1) Creating a task does not start it, so the current logic will always skip the first condition, start the task and no continuation will ever occur.

2) even if you start the task, there is no guarantee that the task will finish in time for the condition checking.. this is why Task.ContinueWith has an overload which accepts a TaskContinuationOptions enumeration.. you have OnlyOnRanToCompletion, OnlyOnFaulted, etc..

3) To sum it up, here is your code, after a little fine tuning

```
  for (int i = 0; i < _paralellTaskCount; i++)
        {
            object message;
            int counter = CheckCounter(message);

            if (counter >= 0)
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() => CalcSingle(_personnelIds[counter].Item1));
                var continuation = task.ContinueWith((antecedent) => CalcSingle(_personnelIds[counter].Item1),
                    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

            }
        }
```

(Note that the continuation receives the antecedent task, which is the task it continues..

4) You do not seem to check if an exception has occured in any task, in any of the many ways provided.. note that wrapping the statement in a try catch clause will not transfer the exception to your thread.. (You need to access the Result or Exception properties, invoke Wait() or use the await keyword in order to accomplish that.

5) Here is an async implementation which does the same, and checks for exceptions

```
 for (int i = 0; i < _paralellTaskCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                object message;
                int counter = CheckCounter(message);

                if (counter >= 0)
                {
                    long res1 = await Task.Run(() => CalcSingle(_personnelIds[counter].Item1));
                    long res2 = await Task.Run(() => CalcSingle(_personnelIds[counter].Item1));
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                //TODO handle
            }
        }
```

6) Please do read some articles which regard TPL, as it seems that you missed a few very important notions.

Comment: The Task constructor doesn't have a high overhead, it just results in cleaner, less error prone code.

Comment: Creating the task via the constructor does not have any special overhead, however creating the task in this manner  does incur an overhead later on.  Since a task can only be started once, creating a task and then starting it causes the task to check if it has already started.. this information is not necessarily present within the instance, thus it can cause some overhead. This issue is presented in any course which covers the TPL.

Comment: Of all of the problems with that code, the time spent checking if the task is already running has to be pretty low on the list. It might not be zero, but it's almost certainly not a problem.

Comment: True that, but still.. :)